# How to store persistent objects per user in the server-side without using databases?

Tags: concurrency, global-variables, asp.net-core-2.0, server-side, static-variables

I need to store a persistent object per user in my .net-core razor-page web application. This object is a collection of structured Lists, strings and numbers. Each user of the application needs to have one unique and persistent object during the application life-time, but different users shouldn't share their objects. This object needs to be accessible and modifiable from any page.

I'm currently using a static class, but I want to avoid concurrency problems. Also, this object need to be stored in the server-side (no sessions and configuration).

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `IMemoryCache` it's a simple object provided by the framework itself which you can cache some data in it per user in your server.
You can simply inject it using DI and use it. Take a look at official documentation working with it is fairly simple and straightforward.
[Memory Cache in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: Thank you @F_IVI_L for your answer. I had a look at the link you provided. They mentioned this sentence in the beginning of the documentation: "Apps should be written and tested to never depend on cached data.". In my case, the application will never function without these objects. Nevertheless, I will try to implement your suggested solution this weekend, then I will come back to you :).

Comment: You shouldn't be using this type of cache in production scenarios, however, you can use it as a hack for simple problems. if you need persistent in-memory data for production you must use other solutions such as Redis or storing it in your Database.